# Anvil Conversion

Tags: autocad, cad

I have an engineer who is currently using the DOS based CAD program called Anvil. We are unable to update his PC. We are looking to convert these to AutoCAD files or is there anyone has successfully updated to Anvil Express? We have one other user using Anvil Express with limited success. We have to run old drivers and non-standard resolutions.

Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

If you can run Anvil, export the files to [IGES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGES) or [STEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303), then import these exchange files into Autocad, or probably more appropriately [Autodesk Inventor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Inventor) (since Anvil is most likely being used for mechanical design).

The data won't likely come through perfectly, but there's probably nothing better to do.